# input[type=radio]:checked + label with background-position-y doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, background-position

CSS selector `input[type=radio]:checked + label` doesn't work in Firefox only!

```css
label {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Muli';
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #666;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: url("https://s31.postimg.org/w3j8tei7f/bullet.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: 12px 52px;
  background-position-y: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=radio] + label {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  background-position-y: -40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="vol-radio">
  <input type="radio" name="volchoice-dates" id="volchoice-dates-flexibles" value="0" checked>
  <label for="volchoice-dates-flexibles">Dates flexibles</label>
  <input type="radio" name="volchoice-dates" id="volchoice-direct" value="1">
  <label for="volchoice-direct">Vol direct</label>
</div>
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `background-position-x` and `background-position-y` are [level 4 CSS](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2014Apr/0188.html)

> - RESOLVED: `background-position-x/-y`, `background-repeat-x/-y`
>         approved for level 4 of `backgrounds` and `borders`.
> - `background-size-x/-y` was also discussed, but didn't garner much
>         support.

---

It isn't supported in Firefox (**yet**, it will be in FF version 50), see [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-position-x-y)

[image: SS]

---

#### you can use [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) instead:

```
input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  background-position: 0 -40px; /* background-position-x | background-position-y  */
}
```

---

```css
label {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Muli';
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #666;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: url("https://s31.postimg.org/w3j8tei7f/bullet.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: 12px 52px;
  background-position: 0 1px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=radio] + label {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  background-position: 0 -40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="vol-radio">
  <input type="radio" name="volchoice-dates" id="volchoice-dates-flexibles" value="0" checked>
  <label for="volchoice-dates-flexibles">Dates flexibles</label>
  <input type="radio" name="volchoice-dates" id="volchoice-direct" value="1">
  <label for="volchoice-direct">Vol direct</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you saying that Firefox doesn't support the `background-position-y` property?

Comment: Thanks a lot, dippas

Comment: Nope. You sometimes get downvotes if you just post code without explanation.